# python - i cant get these lines of code to work properly

Tags: python

I am making a text-based adventure game and there is a part in the game called ans4:(). I'm trying to combine two functions which are ans4 and ans10.

This is the code I have so far:

```
if ans4 and ans10 in answer_yes:
  print("blah blah blah stupid lore stuff blah blah blah blah ")
elif ans7 and ans2 in answer_no:
  print("blah blah blah blah lore blah blah blah blah ")
else:
  print("not a valid answer goodbye")
```

Comment: You need to format the code in the question as it appears in your text editor

Comment: (1) Format the code properly. (2) Explain what the code does and what it should do.

Comment: Are the ans4 and ans10 entities you are referring to really functions? Or are they just variables representing a string or value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your logic, here's the basic structure

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

def ans4():
    #TODO
    #LOGIC
    return True

def ans10():
    #TODO
    #LOGIC
    return False

def ans7():
    #TODO
    #LOGIC
    return True

def ans2():
    #TODO
    #LOGIC
    return False

def ans():
    if ans4() and ans10():
        return ("blah blah blah stupid lore stuff blah blah blah blah ")
    if not ans7() and not ans2():
        return "blah blah blah blah lore blah blah blah blah "
    return "not a valid answer goodbye"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = ans()
    print(f"{result=}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your functions return something(a string or an int), you can do something like this. I'm not sure what you meant by "combine two functions".I guess you meant something like this.

```
answer_yes = 'hey who are you. hello'

def ans4():
     x = 'hello'  # code
    return x # output

def ans10():
    x = 'hey' # code
    return x # output

if ans4() and ans10() in answer_yes:
    print('blah blah')
else:
    print('not a valid answer')
```

output

```
blah blah
```

Edit and apply this code as you need.